# To What Is Stdout Connected When Xcode Is Not Attached?

Tags: ios11, xcode9, foundation

When an app is run via Xcode the result of fputs("Hello World", stdout) appears in the Xcode console. Where does it go when Xcode is not attached? Does the answer change for Debug vs. Release builds? You would think that information such as this would be easy to obtain; surprisingly not.

Update: Hmmm, no answer. The reason that I used fputs as an example is that it explicitly references stdout. But swift's print() function also outputs to stdout. An alternate question might be: What reasons, beyond performance, are there for eliminating print() statements from release builds:

Answer (score 0):

When a GUI app is running under MacOS anything written to the "standard output" is sent to the console, which in turn is written to the console log. The easiest way to view the log is to use the Console app found in Utilities.

As to your alternative question reducing what your app writes to the console avoids cluttering up the console log with useless stuff - just take a look and see the amount of non-useful stuff some apps dump out. As a possible metric, if you as app developer will never ask a user to report something your app has written to the console then your app should not write it there, i.e. don't litter!